# Is there any way to have the method grid inside a frame?

Tags: python, tkinter, spyder

I'm receiving this error when executing the code:

TclError: cannot use geometry manager grid inside .!frame which already has slaves managed by pack.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk
my_window=tk()

frame_name=Frame(my_window)

label_first=Label(frame_name,text="First")
label_first.pack()

label_middle=Label(frame_name,text="Middle")
label_middle.pack()

label_surname=Label(frame_name,text="Surname")
label_surname.pack()

entry_first=Entry(frame_name)
entry_middle=Entry(frame_name)
entry_surname=Entry(frame_name)

button_submit_name=Button(frame_name,text="  Submit  ") 

label_first.grid(row=0,column=0)
label_middle.grid(row=1,column=0)
label_surname.grid(row=2,column=0)

entry_first.grid(row=0,column=1)
entry_middle.grid(row=1,column=1)
entry_surname.grid(row=2,column=1)

button_submit_name.grid(row=3,columnspan=2) 

frame_name.grid(row=0,column=0)

my_window.mainloop()
```

Comment: within each widget, you can only use one geometry manager (`grid`, `pack`, or `place`) - separate widgets can use different geometry managers.

Answer (score 0):

The error is telling  you exactly what is wrong: you can't use both `grid` and `pack` with widgets that have a common master.

The solution is to use one or the other for all widgets that share the same master or parent.